# Developing on both PC (desktop) and mac (laptop) - running PC with homestead and mac with valet. Problems?

Tags: laravel, homestead, laravel-valet

As the title asks. Will this give me problems?

I have created the project on my PC with homestead. Now I took the project code down on my mac laptop with valet. When I went to project.dev in browser I get A red border border on top saying 'Whoops, something went wrong.' and a little ghost with a speach bubble saying 'Exception!'. My console gives me: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server error).

Valet works fine for other non-laravel projects..

Does this have anything to do with the different develop environments that I have? Obviously I want to use valet cos you know. Laziness...

Also it is worth noting it is basically a fresh laravel project we are talking about here. Almost no changes to the code...

Comment: Permissions.... you need to check web-server (Nginx) logs.

Comment: If you're developing, you should have debug enabled, do you not?  If you have debug enabled, it should give you the full error message with a backtrace not just a Whoops error.